# UnknownError when creating a MicrosoftGraph subscription

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am working on a project to set up a webhook with Microsft graph. I have everything set up to validate the endpoint I have created as per (https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/webhooks), however, I am receiving an "Unknown Error" from Microsoft as follows:

```
"__SLOG0__", "{
  \"error\": {
    \"code\": \"UnknownError\",
    \"message\": \"\",
    \"innerError\": {
      \"request-id\": \"d0037849-dc79-4244-bb15-cf72841c6653\",
      \"date\": \"2018-10-22T20:00:43\"
    }
  }
}"
```

I create the subscription with the following values:

```
$body_vals = dict[
      "changeType" => "created,updated",
      "notificationUrl" => $notification_uri,
      "resource" => "/me/mailfolders('inbox')/messages",
      "expirationDateTime" =>
        Office365APIUtils::getISO8601DateStamp($date->getTimestamp()),
      "clientState" => "SecretClientState",
    ]
```

passed into my POST request to the endpoint. I know this has to do with my specific notification uri (which is a facebook endpoint) because if i switch the endpoint to https://google.com, for example, I get a more helpful response:

```
"__SLOG0__", "{
  \"error\": {
    \"code\": \"InvalidRequest\",
    \"message\": \"Subscription validation request failed. Must respond with 200 OK to this request.\",
    \"innerError\": {
      \"request-id\": \"4e2ac4af-4d10-416d-83a1-4eb896a35418\",
      \"date\": \"2018-10-22T19:52:46\"
    }
  }
}"
```

saying I have to validate at the endpoint. I already registered my app, if there is anyone with the Graph team or that has dealt with this before with any leads on these UnknownErrors? an example request-id is 7da743ce-6ffe-4d80-8611-a5be024c8b21

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "facebook endpoint"? How are you validating the subscription and processing incoming notifications?

Comment: Would you mind sharing the timestamp (w/ zone) for the request 7da743ce-6ffe-4d80-8611-a5be024c8b21? Or share another id/time that wasn't mentioned in your post?

Comment: I have an endpoint on the facebook platform that I am exposing to setup this webhook notification system. I am logging any hits to this endpoint and have not recieved any from Microsoft when i attempt to create a subscription to this endpoint. I know it is not an issue with the subsciription object itself that I am sending over because when there were issues with spelling, etc. I recieved a very different error message asking me to check my fields. If i were to get a hit on my endpoint, I validate it according to the dex by sending back the validation token and the correct status code, etc.

Comment: @Trey this is a new request-id/timestamp from latest attempt:  "request-id": "d2e66be2-890d-4da4-a33b-64db772619da",  "date": "2018-10-23T18:37:19" this was made at 2:37pm EST

Comment: I am seeing the same error when trying to subscribe to webhooks:
```
{
 "error": {
  "code": "UnknownError",
  "message": "",
  "innerError": {
   "request-id": "c82c9e05-32a1-4beb-aeb3-8bc8699e38fa",
   "date": "2018-10-24T12:27:05"
  }
 }
}
```

with the following request body
```
{
  "changeType": "updated,deleted",
  "notificationUrl": "https://***-api.facebook.com/***",
  "resource": "users",
  "clientState": "secretstate",
  "expirationDateTime": "2018-10-24T10:26:38Z"
}
```

Changing the notificationUrl to something else will lead to a non-500 response.

Comment: Is your endpoint responding with text/plain content type? There seems to be some error in the encoding your endpoint is responding with.

Comment: Yep it's a 200 with text/plain


<<
$ curl -I  "https://***.facebook.com/***?validationToken=1" -X POST

HTTP/2 200
...
content-type: text/plain;charset=utf-8
...
>>

Comment: Yes me as well I have content-type:text/plain as an included header in my response

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your code may not be performing the endpoint validation step. [This article](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/webhooks#managing-subscriptions) contains a complete walk-through of how to create a subscription. Have a look at the "Notification endpoint validation" section; your endpoint must be able to respond with 200 and include the validation token.

Comment: actually, if you see in the above comments both of us have seen the article and are sending back the validation token within a 200 response...